# Bind an enum to a combo box using knockout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I have not set up my combo box yet;

```
        <tr>
            <td class="leftCell">
                <label class="control-label" for="Title">Status</label>
            </td>
            <td class="rightCell">
                <select id="TenderStatus">
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

Tender Status is an enum set up in Entity Framework;

```
    public enum TenderStatus
    {
        Open,
        Successful,
        Unsuccessful
    }

   public class Tender : IAuditInfoCreated, IAuditInfoModified, IUpdateTender
    {
        public int TenderId { get; set; }

        public string EstimateNumber { get; set; }

        public string Title { get; set; }

        public TenderStatus Status { get; set; }

        public DateTime Created { get; set; }

        public int CreatedBy { get; set; }

        public DateTime? LastModified { get; set; }

        public int LastModifiedBy { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Quote> Quotes { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("{0} - {1}", this.Title, this.EstimateNumber);
        }
    }
```

The combo box allows the user to change the status.
How do I bind this with knockout?
I am using knockout version 3

EDIT
My view model for knockout looks like this. However I cannot bind the SelectList to my view model.

```
var Tender = function () {
    this.tenderId = ko.observable("@Model.Tender.TenderId");
    this.title = ko.observable("@Html.Raw(Model.Tender.Title)");
    this.estimateNumber = ko.observable("@Model.Tender.EstimateNumber");
    this.status = ko.observable("@Model.Tender.Status");
    this.tenderStatusChoices = ko.observable("@Model.TenderStatusChoices");
};
```

@Model.TenderStatusChoices does not return as a collection of items that can bind to a combo. Instead I get a string of "System.Web.Mvc.SelectList"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't send the enum directly to your JavaScript because it's structure is not exposed. All that will ever be passed to the view is the current value it's set to, not all potential values. For that, you'll need to construct some other data structure from the enum. There's many different ways you could do this, but I find it easiest just to send over an actual `SelectList`, so it's already in a fairly usable format.

I use two enum extensions methods:

```
public static SelectList ToSelectList(this Enum en)
{
    var list = (from Enum d in Enum.GetValues(en.GetType())
                select new SelectListItem { Value = Enum.GetName(en.GetType(), d), Text = d.GetDisplayName() }).ToList();

    var selectedValue = Enum.Parse(en.GetType(), Enum.GetName(en.GetType(), en));

    return new SelectList(list, "Value", "Text", selectedValue);
}

public static string GetDisplayName(this Enum en)
{
    Type type = en.GetType();
    System.Reflection.MemberInfo[] memInfo = type.GetMember(en.ToString());

    if (memInfo != null && memInfo.Length > 0)
    {
        object[] attrs = memInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DisplayAttribute), false);

        if (attrs != null && attrs.Length > 0)
            return ((System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DisplayAttribute)attrs[0]).GetName();
    }

    return en.ToString();
}
```

Which you can then use by adding a property to your view model (you should be using view models) such as:

```
public SelectList TenderStatusChoices
{
    get { return TenderStatus.ToSelectList(); }
}
```

Then, with Knockout, you can use the binding:

```
options: TenderStatusChoices, optionsText: 'Text', optionsValue: 'Value', value: Status
```

Comment: I believe this is the right answer. However I cannot bind the Select List to my viewModel

Comment: Why not? If you're not already, you should be JSON-encoding your model for use with Knockout. It makes it much easier to access the underlying data structures. You could manually iterate over `TenderStatusChoices.Items` and construct a JavaScript array, but dealing with JSON is just easier.

Comment: I have just worked out a JSON solution. I am new to Knockout and it seemed a lot of work. I used the JavaScriptSerializer on the server and JSON.parse on the client to convert the string into an array. Now I know this I can do it again much quicker, but I wonder if this is the optimal way of doing it?

Comment: So on your server SelectList getter, I have;
        public string TenderStatusChoices
        {
            get
            {
                var list = Tender.Status.ToSelectList();
                var oSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                return oSerializer.Serialize(list);
            }
        }

Comment: No, it's not the optimal way. You can actually just do something like `var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))`. Or you can could choose to JSON-encode just a portion of your model. But, by putting it raw onto the page, it actually becomes a native JavaScript object (JSON is just JavaScript after all), so no parsing is needed.

Comment: I did as you suggested. I put in var tenderStatusChoices = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.TenderStatusChoices))'; However I still had to use JSON.parse to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below way
In the jquery ready function of your page, you could make an ajax call to one of the method to return enum values as a JSON object. From this you can bind the object by parsing it appropriately into a Viewmodel’s property. 
Next you can use the select tag with options binding to load data into a dropdown